# Building a simple python GUI to open mp3s

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Sorry for the bad question presentation. My issue is that i'm attempting to create a menu bar to open MP3s using window's built in file browser. The GUI appears, but a menu is not present, just the GUI window. No syntax errors however. The goal is to create an Open button and an Exit button within a File menu. All the code below is the entire code..

"""
    Music player
    """

```
from tkinter import *
app = Tk()
app.geometry("600x200")
app.mainloop()
menu = Menu(self.master)
self.master.config(menu=menu)
file = Menu(menu)
file.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.client_exit)
menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file)
```

Comment: Is this code snippet taken from within a class? If not, you shouldn't be using 'self'

Comment: it is not from class, no

Comment: If the entire GUI doesn't appear, you need to provide a more complete code sample.

Comment: Please read about [MCVEs](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and create one for this question. You have provided us a random code snippet, with no explanation, no details about any errors, no definition of the objects you're using, nothing. Please [edit] your question with significantly more information so that we can A) replicate your problem and B) help you solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Code reuse can save you a lot of time, but you have to make sure it all fits together. This means correcting references like `self.master` to `app` and `self.client_exit` to whatever your "open" function is called.

```
from tkinter import *
app = Tk()
app.geometry("600x200")
menu = Menu(app)
file = Menu(menu)
file.add_command(label='Open', command=print) # replace 'print' with the name of your open function
file.add_command(label='Exit', command=app.destroy) # closes the tkinter window, ending the app
menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file)
app.config(menu=menu)
app.mainloop() # at the end
```